# Mogenerator and Xcode 4 advantages/disadvantages

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I am somewhat new to core data integration and have found many code samples and tutorials. Some suggest using Mogenerator to generate entity subclasses. Is this an older approach?

Xcode allows one to generate subclasses for entities without a third party tool. Can anyone offer reasons as to why I would choose to use Mogenerator over the embedded Xcode tool for generating entity subclasses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [article](http://raptureinvenice.com/getting-started-with-mogenerator/) has a detailed explanation of how to use mogenerator with XCode4, and why you would want to.

In developing your app you're likely to add your own custom methods to the generated entity classes (`NSManagedObject` subclasses). But when you run `xctool` to generate the classes, all your changes are overwritten and lost!

Mogenerator generates a pair of classes for each entity - one stable 'machine' class which can be re-generated from the model as you make changes, and one 'human' subclass of the machine class which you can edit and add methods to.

I recommend [adding a target & build phase](http://raptureinvenice.com/getting-started-with-mogenerator/) to your Xcode project which will generate your entity classes at build time, so you never have to remember to run mogenerator manually.

In addition, mogenerator adds const structs containing the attributes of your entitites to the generated classes, so you can avoid using hard-coded strings in your predicates etc.

Comment: Although this adds a dependency to anyone else using the code to have mogenerator installed. Not a problem if you are the sole developer. I prefer to run it manually whenever I change the model.

Comment: @Abizern Absolutely, and this depends on your team & environment. You can add the following to your build phase run script to inform, at least: `command -v mogenerator >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "I require mogenerator but it's not installed. You can install it with 'brew install mogenerator' and then link it with 'sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/mogenerator  /usr/bin/mogenerator'. Aborting."; exit 1; }`. Alternatively, you could check for the presence of mogenerator and only run it if it is installed.

Comment: I don't think you need to manually create a symlink when using homebrew to install mogenerator anymore. I certainly didn't have to.

Comment: xcodebuild doesn't seem to search /usr/local/bin on my machine. One alternative to symlinking is to modify the path `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 5):

Mogenerator has a real advantage if you have to add *instance variables*
(or *properties* backed-up by instance variables) to the managed object subclass.

As David already said, customizing the Xcode generated class file has the big disadvantage
that your changes are lost if you have to re-create the file after modifying the
Core Data entity.

For *methods*, this can be solved by defining the method in a Category on the managed object
subclass, e.g.

```
@interface MyEntity (MyMethods)
- (NSString *)myMethod;
@end
```

However, adding instance variables in a category is not possible (at least not without
using Objective-C runtime tricks such as "associated objects"). And the same applies
to properties if they are backed-up by instance variables.

So if you have that requirement, using mogenerator with the separate class files
is a real advantage. You can add any method, property or instance variable to the 
"Human" class that will not be overwritten.

If you don't need to add instance variables, I don't see a big difference or advantage
for either solution. mogenerator creates some convenience methods and also structs 
containing the property names as strings, but it is your choice if you want to use that
or not.

Comment: +1 Great answer, love how you cover categories and properties. This is also the main benefit to mogenerator in my eyes. My main concern with mongenerator is being dependent on third parties.