# CoreData - Update model class instead of creating new

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am using CoreData in my iOS application. I face a problem most of the times while creating `NSManagedObject` classes.

This is what I do:

1. I create an Entity in `.xcdatamodeld` file.
2. Create attributes and relationships.
3. Choose option `Editor->Create NSManagedObject Class` to create `.h` and `.m` classes.
4. In `.h` and `.m` classes, I create some of my custom methods for fetching/saving objects.

So far so good. But afterwards in future if I have to change some attributes, I repeat step 2 and 3. But this time all of my custom code written in step 4 are removed automatically.

So my question is how can I update the existing classes? Instead of using option `Editor->Create NSManagedObject Class` which removes all my custom code.

Any help is appreciated.

**Update:**

Tested both approaches (Categories and Mogernator) and looks fine to me. But I have choosen Categories  of being a pure Xcode approach. I don't want to take the risk of any 3rd party which may break in future due to XCode updates or can cause problem of data migration.

Thanks to @Tom Harrington, and @Valentin Shamardin for guiding me :)

Comment: You *cannot* update the existing classes, Xcode will always overwrite the files. You can either use categories (as described in the answer below) or use "mogenerator" (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18190845/mogenerator-and-xcode-4-advantages-disadvantages for a comparison). But in both cases you have two classes per entity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To make some additional methods or other stuff for your Core Data model classes you have to create [Categories](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html). This approach is used by Paul Hegarty in Core Data lections.

Comment: How categories can help in above stated case?

Comment: @GMJigar, rewriting  `NSManagedObject` subclasses doesn't rewrite categories classes.

Comment: @Valentin, I have tried creating anonymous category (category in my .m class). And it is still overwritten. Do you have some sample code or link for this?

Comment: Still this overrides the class's whole contents.

Comment: @Khawar, Core Data Demo (November 10, 2011). Paul creates categories at 0:45:00

Comment: If I create separate classes for categories, the number of files would be just doubled. I don't want to use this. Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: @ValentinShamardin, I have downloaded the sample code of Paul, and ran it. I can see he has created separate category classes. But that doubles the number of files. My application would already have more than 30 entities. So if I use separate category classes, it can go upto 60 :(. I don't want to do that.

Comment: @Khawar, wow! 30 entities is really huge number. But I don't know other ways.

Comment: What is your concern with having 60 files? Many projects have far more files than that. I have a project with about 30 entities as well, I use categories for all my customizations, and it's very manageable.

Comment: @ChrisVasselli, I don't have any serious problem with external category classes, I just wanted to have lesser number of files so that I could manage easily. Secondly I was looking if there is any other simple way of doing this.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to handle this is to use [mogenerator](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator) to generate your model classes instead of having Xcode do it. With mogenerator you get two classes for each entity:

- One that is re-generated every time you rebuild the model classes
- One that is a subclass of the other, which is only generated the first time you build model classes and which mogenerator never changes afterward.

As a result you can put all your custom code in the subclass, and no matter how many times you re-generate your model classes, your code is never overwritten.

Comment: This is what I was going to write - `mogenerator` has saved me a lot of time.

Comment: @Tom Harrington, I have tried `mogenerator` and feeling good. Just wanted to know your best practices for Modal files placement. Currently `mogenerator` just puts all 4 files for each Entity in my `Modals` directory/group. I have almost 30 entities means 120 files. Which would make it difficult to search. So what should I do? Should I create a group for each entity or just create 2 groups (First for all `_` files and second for all custom files).

The other concern I wanted to confirm, wouldn't it create any problem for Modal migration in future?

Comment: I like to create one Xcode group for the files that get regenerated every time (the ones with `_`) and a separate group for the rest. Creating a group for each entity doesn't really help since you'll have way too many groups. None of this has anything to do with model migration.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever yo change or update your core data object model it becomes incompatible and cannot be open and as a result it gives crashes.
For this you need to perform Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration. 
Versioning is nothing just only provides you which model version is application going to use. Changes and update in core data model like modifying any attribute of entity or adding new entity. It is related with Core database model. Consider your application going to use 1.0 ver and using database model of 1. if u have some changes in database model its version increases and now you application going to use next version ie 2 of core database model

The details refer to this [Apple Doc for Core Data Versioning](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html)

Also this will result in old Data loss. For this you need to perform Migration Process.
During migration, Core Data creates two stacks, one for the source store and one for the destination store. Core Data then fetches objects from the source stack and inserts the appropriate corresponding objects into the destination stack".

Please refer to Migration Process details on [Migration on Raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/27657/how-to-perform-a-lightweight-core-data-migration)

You need to use [NSMigrationManager class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSMigrationManager_class/Reference/NSMigrationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSMigrationManager) and

Comment: thanks for reply, but i am not interested in Core Data Versioning or Migration. It is irrelevant to my question. :)