# How to add attributes to an NSManagedObject subclass created by the data model file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a basic notes app and I'm learning to work with Core Data, so what I learned is that now all of the models that are part of my MVC, like a `Note.h` and `Note.m` that have all the data of a note will now be created through the data model file of Core Data through entities. So I have created a `Note` entity, I gave it an `NSString` `content` attribute and created a `NSManagedObject` subclass (like they teach in the Stanford videos), but I'm wondering if now I want to add a new attribute to Note model how would I do that? Should I manually add it in the data model file of Core Data and than manually to the `Note.h` and `.m` files? this creation through the editor got me confused a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After changes to the Core Data entities, you must *recreate* the managed object subclass
files via "Editor -> Create NSManagedObject Subclass …" from the Xcode menu. Manually
editing these files only bears the danger of introducing errors.

Alternatively, use tools like ["mogenerator"](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator) to create and update the files automatically.
See (for example) [Mogenerator and Xcode 4 advantages/disadvantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18190845/mogenerator-and-xcode-4-advantages-disadvantages) for a comparison between "mogenerator" and the built-in Xcode 
file generation.

Comment: is creating categories can be a solution for this matter? @Martin R

Comment: @user3508380: If you want to add *additional* instance variables to the class (that are *not* part of the Core Data model), then categories are a possible solution, and "mogenerator" is another possible solution. If you add a new attribute to the *model* then you should recreate the files (but that seems to be opinion-based).

Comment: MOGenerator is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should manually add it in the data model file of Core Data and than manually to the `Note.h` and `Note.m` files.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in different ways...The simplest way is to add your attribute to your entity and then 1) manually insert a new property to your `Note` subclass or 2) use Xcode to do it for you.

If you follow the second way, using *Editor -> Create NSManagedObject Subclass …*, Xcode will ask you to overwrite existing files. So if you have performed customization on those files they will disappear...

My personal taste. I prefer the first way. The manually one.

An important note is the following. If you have already an app that has already set up a persistent store, and then you change the model, when you will relaunch the app it will crash since there is a difference between the two models. Solutions are or deleting the application and run it again or use light migration. e.g. [how-to-perform-a-lightweight-core-data-migration](http://www.raywenderlich.com/27657/how-to-perform-a-lightweight-core-data-migration)